# Adding custom markers to Google Maps in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am trying to add custom markers to Google Maps in my flutter app. For now, I only want to display markerId and LatLng for each marker. The data for the marker is below:

```
[0]: Marker (Marker{markerId: MarkerId(PO Box 391054, Mountain View, CA 94039), alpha: 1.0, anchor: Offset(0.5, 1.0), consumeTapEvents: false, draggable: false, flat: false, icon: Instance of 'BitmapDescriptor', infoWindow: InfoWindow{title: null, snippet: null, anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.0)}, position: LatLng(37.4188, -122.0909), rotation: 0.0, visible: true, zIndex: 0.0, onTap: null, onDragStart: null, onDrag: null, onDragEnd: null})
```

Here is the code where I create the markers in a list and pass that list to the map file in the FloatActionButton onPress:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/property_information_model.dart';
import 'google_map_screen.dart';
import 'widgets/address_information_card.dart'; // Tiles for displaying tax property info
import '../screens/widgets/address_input.dart'; // TextFields for inputting the address
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart'; // Need this for the list of markers

const String zipCode = '';

class TaxDataScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String zipCode = zipController.text;

  TaxDataScreen(zipController, {super.key});

  @override
  _TaxDataScreenState createState() => _TaxDataScreenState();
}

class _TaxDataScreenState extends State<TaxDataScreen> {
  List<PropertyInformation> propertyList = [];
  List<Marker> resultMarkers = [];

  bool isLoaded = false;

  Future<void> getItems() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoaded = true;
    });
    var client = http.Client();

    try {

      // This is the tax data API call
      var url = Uri.parse(
          "https://realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com/properties?zipCode=${widget.zipCode}");

      final response = await client.get(
        url,
        headers: {
          'X-RapidAPI-Key':
              '51ced1b32emsh509f82e1d58ae16p1ad6e6jsn75d75166a8b4',
          'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com'
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

        for (var element in jsonData) {
          element.removeWhere((key, value) => key == null || value == null);
        }

        // decode the json
        for (var i in jsonData) {
          propertyList.add(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i));

          // Create marker from the search results for Google Maps
          resultMarkers.add(
            Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(
                  PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).formattedAddress.toString()),
              //position: LatLng(double.tryParse(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).latitude!) ?? 0.0 , double.tryParse(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).longitude!) ?? 0.0)
              position: LatLng(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).latitude!,
                  PropertyInformation.fromJson(i).longitude!),
            ),
          );
        }
      } else {
        //print('Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = false;
      });
      log("error $e");
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoaded = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getItems();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(
          child: Text('Data'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: isLoaded
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: propertyList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return AddressInformationCard(
                    propertyInfo: propertyList[index],
                  );
                },
              ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.map_sharp),
        label: const Text('Map'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MapPropertySearchResults(resultMarkers)));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the screen where I have Google Maps and want to display the markers:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MapPropertySearchResults extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Marker> resultMarkers = [];
  MapPropertySearchResults(resultMarkers, {super.key});

  @override
  State<MapPropertySearchResults> createState() =>
      _MapPropertySearchResultsState();
}

class _MapPropertySearchResultsState extends State<MapPropertySearchResults> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;

  late LatLng _currentPosition;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

  getLocation() async {
    // Get user permission to use current location
    bool serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error("Location permission not granted");
    }

    // LocationPermission permission;
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error("Location permission denied");
      }
    }

    // This gets the current location on Google Maps
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    LocationSettings locationSettings = const LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 100);

    // This will show where the user is going in real time
    Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
        .listen((Position position) {});
    double lat = position.latitude;
    double long = position.longitude;

    LatLng location = LatLng(lat, long);

    setState(() {
      _currentPosition = location;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: _currentPosition,
                zoom: 11.0,
              ),
              markers: { <<< PUT MARKERS HERE
```

, // Marker
},
),
);
}
}

How do I add my list of markers to the Google Maps markers?

Comment: Create a `Set<Marker> _markers` in your state, then add your markers to the `GoogleMap.markers` parameter and call `setState`.